# Joomla Article Partial Restriction

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

New to Joomla 2.5, have a quick question.

Whether or not it is doable seems to be the issue. I do see similar stuff regarding 1.5 but it is a few years old.

Is it possible to show two versions of one article one to non logged in user and one to logged in users?

Essentially, I need to show a blurb with an overview specific to the article and some text encouraging the user to register, if a user is not logged in. If they are logged in then I need to show an embedded video.

I am familiar with read more link functionality. Unfortunately, for me that is not 100% what client is looking for - it was my first suggestion. They want something a little more robust and they don't want the blurb to be there if the user is authenticated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the [Sourcerer Plugin](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) Then use this to write a database query checking if the user is logged in or not. You can then base what content is visible on that query using an `if -else` statement

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the core "show unauthorized" feature which shows the introtext but not the full text to guests. But default there is a "register to read more" link provided. However between template overrides, plugins etc you can do fancier.